# pyglet NoSuchConfigException error

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, windows-7-x64, nvidia, pyglet

I am trying to get started with `pyglet` with a `Hello World` example posted on their site. Even the simplest lines code result in an error:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/__init__.py", line 306, in __getattr__
    __import__(import_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1684, in <module>
    gl._create_shadow_window()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/gl/__init__.py", line 494, in  _create_shadow_window
    _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 474, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 641, in __init__
    raise NoSuchConfigException('No standard config is available.')
pyglet.window.NoSuchConfigException: No standard config is available.
```

I use `Python 2.7.8` and `Pyglet 1.1.4` on `Ubuntu 12.04`. I have an nVidia geforce gt 540m card, driver version `304.116`.

Edit: I tried the same thing on `Windows 7` (on the same machine) and got a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\__init__.py", line 306, in __getatt
r__
    __import__(import_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 1684, in
<module>
    gl._create_shadow_window()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\gl\__init__.py", line 494, in _crea
te_shadow_window
        _shadow_window = Window(width=1, height=1, visible=False)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 423
, in __init__
    super(Win32Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 686, in _
_init__
    self._create()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 467
, in _create
    _user32.RegisterClassW(byref(self._window_class))
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

The `Python`and `Pyglet` versions are the same, and the nVidia driver is `337.88`.

Answer (score -1):

I hit this issue too, after searching on Google, I notice that Ubuntu team has fixed it in their release, so I solve this issue by running the following two commands:

```
sudo pip uninstall pyglet
sudo apt-get install python-pyglet
```